# Bokeh plot line

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I tried to write these codes to display the dataseries plot, but no data was not displayed.
I dont know where is the problem exactly.

```
data=pd.read_csv('weather.csv')[['STA','Date','Precip','MaxTemp','MinTemp','MeanTemp','Snowfall']].dropna()
data = data[data['Precip'] != 'T']
data['Precip'].astype(float)
data['STA']=data['STA'].astype("string")
data['Date']=pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
stations=list(set(data['STA']))
stations.sort()
select_inital=select.value
colors = list(Category20_16)
colors.sort()
subset=data[data['STA']==select_inital]
initial_values= list(set(subset['STA']))
for i, j in enumerate(initial_values):
   subset=data[data['STA']==j]
   d=subset[['Date','Precip']]
   d.sort_values('Date')
   x=d['Date']
   y=d['Precip']
   d = ColumnDataSource(d)

p = figure(plot_width=700, plot_height=700, x_range=(0,200), title='Weather      Evolution',x_axis_label='Date', y_axis_label='Precip',x_axis_type='datetime')
p.line(x,y, legend_label="Evolution", line_width=2)
show(p)
```

Comment: There is not enough information here to speculate. Are there error messages in the browser's JavaScript console? Please provide a complete [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be run in order to investigate directly.

Answer (score 1):

This is just guessing but I believe the problem is, that you are trying to set limits to the `x_range`. Bokeh is evaluating dates as milliseconds from 1970-01-01 00:00 and your `x_range=(0,200)` is also interpreted as millisecond. This means the visible area is very small and starts at January 1st 1970. You could use the defaults by bokeh instead.

### Minimal example

This is your code for the figure except I removed the `x_range`.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

x = pd.date_range('2022-12-01', '2022-12-24', freq='D')
y = list(range(1,25))

p = figure(
    plot_width=700,
    plot_height=700,
    # x_range=(0,200),
    title='Weather      Evolution',
    x_axis_label='Date',
    y_axis_label='Precip',
    x_axis_type='datetime'
)
p.line(x,y, legend_label="Evolution", line_width=2)
show(p)
```

| Bokeh default `x_range` | `x_range` by user |
| --- | --- |
| [image: with default range] | [image: with set x_range] |

### Comment

If you want to set the `x_range` for a axis with type `"datetime"` you can pass timestamp objects to it.

Valid are among other things (e.g. float)

```
# datetime
from datetime import datetime
x_range=(datetime(2022,12, 7),datetime(2022,12, 10))

# pandas
import pandas as pd
x_range=(pd.Timestamp('2022-12-07'),pd.Timestamp('2022-12-10'))
```